# Clearing Panel Jumps to Value Change Event of DatePicker and Never ends the loop

Tags: vb.net

Here I am using Panel with some dynamic datetime editors on windows forms with VB.net. Before loading the panel i am trying to clear the panel. But this cause value changed event to run continuously and will never stop

When the date is entered in dynamically created datetime editor, value changed event is continuously running and will never stop.

How can I fix this

My code is as Below

```
 Private Function LoadFlow()

        Me.UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls.Clear()


        Dim i As Integer = 0


        'Check if datatable has rows and is not null
        If dtFlowPanel.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso dtFlowPanel IsNot Nothing Then



            Do While (i < dtFlowPanel.Rows.Count)

                'DatePicker
                dtpicker = New UltraDateTimeEditor
                dtpicker.Name = "Date" + i.ToString()
                dtpicker.MaskInput = "{date} hh:mm"
                dtpicker.MaskDisplayMode = MaskMode.IncludeBoth
                dtpicker.SpinButtonDisplayStyle = Infragistics.Win.ButtonDisplayStyle.Always
                dtpicker.Height = 20
                dtpicker.Width = 140
                'horizontal
                dtpicker.Location = New Point((i * 140), 100)

                AddHandler dtpicker.ValueChanged, AddressOf dtpicker_ValueChanged

                If Not IsDBNull(dtFlowPanel.Rows(i)("CheckPointTimeValue")) Then
                    dtpicker.Value = dtFlowPanel.Rows(i)("CheckPointTimeValue")
                Else
                    dtpicker.Value = Nothing
                End If


                Me.UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls.Add(dtpicker)

                i = (i + 1)

            Loop
        End If

        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

My value changed event

```
 Private Sub dtpicker_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(chkdtFlowPanel.Rows.Item(0).Item("ConveyanceID")) AndAlso Not DBNull.Value.Equals(chkdtFlowPanel.Rows.Item(0).Item("TripID")) Then
            ScreenProperty.ARG_ConveyanceID = chkdtFlowPanel.Rows.Item(0).Item("ConveyanceID")
            ScreenProperty.ARG_TripID = chkdtFlowPanel.Rows.Item(0).Item("TripID")
            Dim prevDatevalue As Object = Nothing
            For Each o As Object In UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls
                If TypeOf (o) Is UltraDateTimeEditor Then
                    Dim datePicker As UltraDateTimeEditor = o

                    If datePicker.Value <> Nothing Then

                       If prevDatevalue <> Nothing Then
                            If datePicker.Value < prevDatevalue Then
                                ' Do something Previous value is Lesser
                                'lblSuccess.Text = "Please verify date entered."
                                'lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Red
                                Exit Sub
                            End If
                        End If


                        ScreenProperty.ARG_CheckPointTimeID = Convert.ToInt32(datePicker.Tag.Split(","c)(0))
                        ScreenProperty.ARG_TerminalCheckPointID = Convert.ToInt32(datePicker.Tag.Split(","c)(1))
                        ScreenProperty.ARG_CheckPointTimeValue = datePicker.Value
                        Helper.InsertCheckPointTimes(CType(ScreenProperty, KMCommonUITemplates.CUTScreenProperty), Me)
                        prevDatevalue = datePicker.Value
                       'ClearText()

                    End If
                    'lblSuccess.Text = "Data Saved Successfully."
                    'lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Green
                End If
            Next
            'Else
            '    lblSuccess.Text = "Selected Order does not have Trip/Conveyance created."
            '    lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Helper.GetCheckPointFlowByTerminalID(CType(ScreenProperty, KMCommonUITemplates.CUTScreenProperty), Me)
            LoadFlow()
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: So you have verified that removing a `UltraDateTimeEditor ` from its container control causes its `ValieChanged` event to fire?  If so, try removing the event handler from the control before removing the control from its container.  You should be doing this in any case.

Comment: @TnTinMn How can I remove event handler

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `c.ValueChanged-= dtpicker_ValueChanged`

Comment: Dynamic controls is something you ought not decide to do frivolously.  Open TaskManager add Handles, GDI Objects and User Objects, then run your app - you will see it is leaking.

Answer (score 0):

Since the event handler code is calling `LoadFlow` that in turn appears to trigger the eventhandler, you are entering an infinite loop.

Before the statement `Me.UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls.Clear()` in `LoadFlow` remove any eventhandlers.  Something like this:

```
For Each c As Control In UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls
    Dim dtp As UltraDateTimeEditor 
    dtp = TryCast(c, UltraDateTimeEditor)
    If dtp IsNot Nothing Then
        RemoveHandler dtp.ValueChanged, AddressOf DateTimePicker_ValueChanged
    End If
Next
```